# web3js 1.0.0-beta.24 The returned value is not a convertible string:

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to read symbol from this contract https://etherscan.io/address/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0#readContract but getting en error `The returned value is not a convertible string`. Here is my code:

`const contractInstance = new Config.web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0x86Fa049857E0209aa7D9e616F7eb3b3B78ECfdb0");`

`const symbol = contractInstance.methods.symbol().call();`

`symbol.then((res) => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})`

At the same time i'm able to read `name`, `totalSupply`, `decimals`.Is there is any way to read contract `symbol` ?

Comment: Are you perhaps using the wrong ABI? When I use the ABI from https://etherscan.io/address/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0#code, your code works fine for me. Note that `symbol` is a `bytes32`.

Comment: As for how to convert it to a string, this works, though I wonder if there's an easier way: `web3.utils.hexToAscii('0x454f530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000').replace(/\u0000*$/, '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the correct ABI should fix the issue. Complete working code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/<REDACTED>');

// Stripped down ABI from https://etherscan.io/address/0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0#code,
// with just the function we care about.
const abi = [
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "symbol",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "bytes32"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  }
];

new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0')
.methods.symbol().call()
.then((symbol) => {
  const symbolString = web3.utils.hexToAscii(symbol).replace(/\u0000*$/, '');
  console.log(symbolString);
});

// Output:
// EOS
```

Comment: You right. I used next ABI: 
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "symbol",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },

Comment: Is there is a way to get ABI for a contract without calling etherscan ?.

Comment: The ABI can be published anywhere, but Etherscan is the most popular place. You can generate the ABI yourself from source code, but either way you need the source code to be published.

Comment: By the way, the ERC20 standard dictates that `symbol` returns a `string`, so it looks like the issue you ran into is largely because this token doesn't follow the standard.